# How To Place Children Items of my Custom Item at my desired Location? (QML)

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Assuming I want to create my CustomItem

```
//MyCustomItem.qml
RowLayout{
        spacing: 0

        Image{
            id: divider
            source: "qrc:/screen_header/vertical_divider_screen_header.png"

        }


        Item{ //THIS PART HERE SHOULD ALWAYS BE THE CHILDREN ITEMS 
            id:mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }

        Image{
            id: divider2
            source: "qrc:/screen_header/vertical_divider_screen_header.png"

        }
}
```

I want to use this CustomItem and every children should be automatically be placed inside "Item" but the Layout.alignment should persist.

For Example

Placing an image inside would result in

```
  //main.qml
  MyCustomItem{
            Image{
                source: "qrc:/test.png"
            }  
        }
```

[image]

Placing a Text inside would result in

```
   MyCustomItem{
            Text{
                text: "AUTO"
            }  
        }
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a default property to automagically direct the Image/Text into `mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE` with the following code:

```
default property alias children: mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE.data
```

Note that this allows *multiple* elements inside MyCustomItem (including non-visual ones). If you don't want this, you can use a Control ([Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html)) instead of `mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE` and alias to `contentItem`.

---

Btw, the `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter` that you really want will not work, since the RowLayout will assign the Item a place on the horizontal axis based on the items. It does work for Qt.AlignVCenter since that is perpendicular to the layout direction.

With the following code you can center all contents in the middle like in your images:

```
RowLayout {
    default property alias data: mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE.data

    Rectangle { //replace with your Divider.png
        width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "white"
    }

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        implicitWidth:  mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE.childrenRect.width
        implicitHeight: mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE.childrenRect.height

        Item{ //THIS PART HERE SHOULD ALWAYS BE THE CHILDREN ITEMS
            id:mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE
            width: childrenRect.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

By using the implicitWidth and implicitHeight, the RowLayout will also grow according to the content that you put in. The other way around also works, you can give width/height for MyCustomItem on the place where you use it

Comment: Hey thanks for answering my question and also fixing my mistake with the Layout. What could be a drawback of adding non-visual items inside of my item or why are you pointing it out?

Comment: It's not a drawback, it might be handy! For example a C++ model that retrieves data from some external source, to name something. However, placing multiple visual items might get you slightly unanticipated results ;-)  excuse me for slightly confusing phrasing that

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a [default property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties). If you define your default property to be the data field of your Item, then by default all child objects will become children of that Item.

```
//MyCustomItem.qml
RowLayout{
        default property alias contents: mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE.data

        Item{
            id:mid_item_TEXT_OR_IMAGE
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
}
```